# Windows XP doesn't want to Hibernate, instead returns to desktop

Tags: windows-xp, hibernate

Hibernate was just working fine under my Windows XP Laptop and something happened to it.

Now when I press the power button in my laptop (it is setup to hibernate) the blue shutdown screen appears and I see the Hibernate label on it, but after 1-2 seconds it goes away and comes back on the screen I was just having before.

The same happens when I press the hibernate (via pressing shift) on the shutdown chooser.

I checked and there is 12 gigabyte of free space on the hard drive. The laptop has only 1Gb of ram.

What could be the problem?

**Edit**

The output of

```
C:\>powercfg /a
The following sleep states are available on this system: Standby ( S3 ) Hibernat
e
The following sleep states are not available on this system:
Standby (S1)
Standby (S2)
```

The output of

```
C:\>powercfg /devicequery wake_armed
Conexant HDA D110 MDC V.92 Modem
```

Comment: Might be some kind of software stopping it from hibernating.

Answer (score 1):

Open the command prompt and do the following:

```
C:
cd \
dir /a hiberfil.sys
```

If it's not there, then go into power options, disable hibernation, reboot, then enable hibernation and reboot again.

If that doesn't work, open up the command prompt again (make sure you are an admin) update your question with the output of the following commands:

```
powercfg /a
powercfg /devicequery wake_armed
```

Comment: See my edit to the question for updates.

Comment: Try going into device manager, find Conexant HDA D110 MDC V.92 Modem, double-click on it, go to the Power Management tab, uncheck "Allow this device to wake the computer", then click OK.  Reboot and see if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try disconnecting all devices when you hibernate. Yes, that includes mouse/keyboard. Just disconnect it right after you press hibernate.

Comment: It's a laptop, cannot disconnect it.